# Testcafe connects very slow to dev URL

Tags: testing, automated-tests, connection, e2e-testing, testcafe

[image]I am trying to test a Dev URL using Testcafe framework in my corp network via proxy. it all worked fine when it was running locally. But when I initialized git into my project Testcafe browser start connecting to test URL very slow. it sounds weird but just wanted to check if any configuration impacts testcafe browser to connect to URL. While in Chrome I can connect to URL smoothly.

Monitored the network tab on testcafe browser and found some errors where it is trying to use static URLs and some javascript error. I tried 
testcafe chrome tests/ --skip-js-errors --proxy eXXXXXX:8080

{
  "name": "mXXXXuiautomation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "testcafe chrome tests/ --skip-js-errors --proxy eXXXXX:8080"
  },

Using npm test to run my test

Expected: Testcafe browser should connect to URL in a smooth way with minimal execution time

Actual: It connects very slowly and some tests fail because an element is not found in the expected time

Comment: It looks like slow performance of your corporate proxy. Could you please describe how you specify the proxy settings for Google Chrome browser in detail?

Comment: @mlosev Google chrome uses pac file to use proxy. but through application i explicitly mention proxy as mentioned above in my commands. 
"testcafe chrome tests/ --skip-js-errors --proxy eXXXXX:8080"

Comment: This information is not sufficient to find the cause of the issue, because it is related to your environment. You can try to debug the [testcafe-hammerhead](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead) proxy server of TestCafe.